# Accessing the attributes of an Asset field

Tags: assets, assetfilemodel, attribute

Specifically looking at these attributes http://d.pr/i/1ilbr

I can access Alt text by `{{ entry.assetHandle.first().altText }}` and similarly can do `{{ entry.assetHandle.first().sourceUrl }}` but Source Name continues to be elusive.

I'm confused as to whether this is an attribute or part of the AssetSourceModel? Although would assume attribute given it's editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `Alt Text` (handle `altText`), `Source Name` (handle `sourceName`) and `Source URL` (handle `sourceUrl` are all plain text custom fields you've created on your Assets.

If so, you'd be able to access `sourceUrl` the same as the others:

```
{{ entry.assetHandle.first().sourceUrl }}
```

They definitely aren't attributes on Craft's [AssetSourceModel](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/models/AssetSourceModel.php#L80).

Comment: you know what, I'm dumb. I didn't build out the initial site, I didn't even think to check if those were custom fields. I assumed (wrongly) obviously that they were native to an Asset field (I know EE's Assets field has similar attributes).